# Why is unmute not working with amixer command?

Tags: linux-terminal

I am trying to mute and unmute using amixer command at terminal in Linux.

The command used to mute:

```
 amixer sset 'Master' mute
```

AND

```
amixer set Master mute
```

Both worked...

But when I try to unmute:

```
amixer sset 'Master' unmute
```

AND

```
amixer set Master unmute
```

It doesn't work and volume is still mute.

Both unmute code lines tried return this output in the terminal:

> Simple mixer control 'Master',0   Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined
>   pswitch pswitch-joined   Playback channels: Mono   Limits: Playback 0
>   - 87   Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]

How can I make amixer works to unmute and why it doesn't toggle off? 
It is amixer the better command to control volume in Linux OS*? If not what tool better instead of amixer?

*Note: Linux OS in general, because it should work to all Linux distro with the less chance to incompatibility and code variation to mute/unmute sound.

Comment: In the examples you show, you can leave out the quotes (```'```). You need quotes only when you’re using shell variables, command substitutions, and strings with certain non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from this [post](http://www.arvydas.co.uk/2012/08/muteunmute-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-using-command-line/) Arvydas write :

> For some reason, muting works fine, but unmuting or toggle has no effect. Upon further investigation I noticed that by muting Master channel, “PCM” and “Master Mono” channels are muted too. Unmuting Master does not unmute those two channels.

That work for me on ubuntu 14.04 (qtile WM) to unmute :

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 0
```

to mute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 1
```

---

### Updated:

There a lot of reports on this issue [Bug #1026331](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-utils/+bug/1026331) and [Bug #878986](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/878986)  in launchpad ,
if you mute/toggle master:

```
amixer set Master mute
```

Other channels(Headphone and Speaker in my case) will mute also. but if you unmute/toggle Master :

```
amixer set Master unmute
```

the Other Channels will stay mute , but 
if you try unmute Headphone and Speaker channels sound will come back

```
amixer set Master unmute
amixer set Headphone unmute
amixer set Speaker unmute
```

Answer (score 2):

xdotool can be troublesome sometimes, fortunately PulseAudio now provides commands for volume regulation and mute.

try this command: `pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle` to toggle mute.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Keyboard_volume_control

Answer (score 2):

All above existing answers either use `pactl` or `xdotool`, here is a [`amixer` specific answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65764/how-do-i-toggle-sound-with-amixer#286437):

This works for both mute and unmute:

`amixer -D pulse set Master toggle`

It specifies pulse audio to ensure unmute, unmutes everything.

- It works from 13.04, to 17.10 and all the way to current Ubuntu and Debian
- There was a `1+` in the original answer, but the reason for it is unknown, and *"It works even better without the `1+` parameter"*
- Some claims that even **`amixer set Master toggle`** works, and I've confirmed that it works for my Debian 10.

Comment: This worked for me to map a single key to mute/unmute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have discover the "xdotool" to simulate media keys. It's simple, because is the same code to toggle mute:

> xdotool key XF86AudioMute

And it show the visual notification...

So for further uses of "xdotool":

https://askubuntu.com/questions/235126/simulate-media-keys-in-terminal

Answer (score -1):

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ toggle
```

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: Found from this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65764/how-do-i-toggle-sound-with-amixer#286437

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  I think that what Pierre was hinting at is that just a command line isn't a great answer (even if it's correct).  People often misinterpret questions, so the reader can't be sure it's even an answer to the right question, or whether there might be assumptions or limitations that would affect the next reader's ability to apply it to a slightly different case.  Aside, from that, a good answer educates the reader so they understand why and how it's the solution, so they might be able to answer the next variation themselves.  Can you add some explanation?  Thanks.